# 2 activities in a single tab

Tags: android, tabs

I have 4 tabs. One Tab 1 (Respond) I want to start another activity say click on continue button and should go to another page (Respond1) where I have back button. Everything should be on Tab 1 itself. I am having problems like if I go 4 to 5 times I get stack over flow error.

Respond.Java

```
package com.muo.Livegroups;

import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.util.Log;

public class Respond extends ActivityGroup 
{
    protected static LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "muo";
    @Override   
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.respond);

        //Continue button on Respond page
        Button next1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Continue);
        next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Respond1.class);
                startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            //  StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
            //  myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //  replaceContentView("Respond1",myIntent);

                int mInt=0;
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "mInt Value: " + mInt);
            }
        });
    }

    public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) 
    {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager()
                        .startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY ))
                        .getDecorView(); 
        this.setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

Respond1.Java

```
package com.muo.Livegroups;

import android.app.ActivityGroup;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Respond1 extends ActivityGroup 
{
    protected static LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager;
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "muo1";
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.respond1);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View view) 
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                finish();
            //  Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Respond.class);
            //  StringBuffer urlString = new StringBuffer();
            //  myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            //  replaceContentView("Respond",intent);

                int mInt1=0;
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "mInt Value: " + mInt1);
            }
        });
    }

    public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) 
    {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager()
                        .startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ))
                        .getDecorView(); 
        this.setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://androidgenuine.com/ check this example of ActivityGroup

Answer (score 1):

You should consider making the two activities [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) and putting them together in one activity in the tab. If you're using an api level less than 3.0, please look at the [android compatibility package](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Answer (score 0):

> main activitity should be ActivityGroup and put this code where you start new activity

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity1.class);
Activity1 parentActivity = (Activity1)getParent();  
parentActivity.replaceContentView("activity1", intent, 
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT );
```